# $(A\cdot B)^\ast=B^\ast\cdot A^\ast$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It's true that $(A\cdot B)^\ast=B^\ast\cdot A^\ast$, where $A, B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, $n\geq 2$?

Here $A^\ast$ is [the adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $A$.

For $n=2$ it's true. Also for invertible matrix. I think it's false in general but I didn't found a counterexample.

Comment: Tip: a better notation for sets of real matrices is $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

Comment: @K.defaoite Both notations are standard, and I disagree with your opinion that one is necessarily "better".

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose it comes down to preference.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's true.

One easy proof is as follows: the function $f(A) = A^*$ is continuous. Since for any matrices $A,B$ there exists a sequence of invertible matrices $A_n,B_n$ such that $A_n \to A$ and $B_n \to B$, we have
$$
(AB)^* = \lim_{n \to \infty}(A_n B_n)^* = \lim_{n \to \infty} B_n^*A_n^* = B^*A^*.
$$

Comment: Hi, I'm not very familiar with matrix analysis. How is continuity of matrix valued functions defined?

Comment: @K.defaoite You could either say that a function is continuous if it is continuous as a function of the individual entries, or you could define continuity relative to any [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) (it turns out that any of these defintiions are equivalent).

Comment: Adding to that, "equivalent" means that if we have two different ways of defining the norm (i.e. two different functions), say f(X) and g(X), Then there exist $C_1,C_2$ positive numbers such that $f(X)<=C_1g(X), g(X)<=C_2f(X)$ holds for every matrix X.

Comment: @Divide1918 That is the usual definition of equivalence between norm, but I think that the more relevant and intuitive definition of "equivalent" here is that a function over/to the set of matrices will be continuous relative to one norm (or under the entrywise definition of continuity) if and only if it is continuous relative to another.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Seems so. However, the two definitions are equivalent, so one may choose whichever definition they prefer when they use this concept of equivalence to solve problems